# React sending props withoutid

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-props

```
<Description
    description={description}
/>
```

In Description component I can display name and other pool but not id. I diplay in console.log what is in this props and it is all without id, created_at and updated_at. Why? How can I send props with id? Let me just mention that in parent component everything is ok.

@Update

```
export default function Description({description}){
    const showDescription = (description) => {
        console.log(description);
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>{description.id} {description.title}</h2>
            <div><button onClick={ () => showDescription(description) }
            >Click</button></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

@Update2
For the test I tryed send id like a new props. I show you too more code

```
    <>
    <ul>
        {descriptions.map(description =>
        {description.id}
        <li
            key={description.id}>
            {description.id} <span onClick={
                () => handleClick(desscription)}>{description.na

me}
                </span>
            </li>)}
        </ul>
        <Description
            id={description.id}
            description={description}
        />
        </>
```

React display id in list (li) but if I send that in props, Description component desplay undefined.

Comment: Make it clear so that others can understand you. For example, exact data about `description`, simple explanation about `Description` component. etc.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: What is the result of `console.log`? If it does not contain `id`, how did you get `description` data?

Comment: console.log display object without id. Problem is that before send object in props id is in this object. Look at Upadate2

Answer (score 0):

```
import Description from "./Description";

export default function App() {
  const descriptions = [
    { id: 1, title: "Foo", name: "Alex" },
    { id: 2, title: "Bar", name: "Mike" }
  ];

  const handleClick = (d) => {
    console.log(d);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {descriptions.map((description) => (
          <li key={description.id}>
            <span onClick={() => handleClick(description)}>
              {description.name}
            </span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <Description id={descriptions.id} description={descriptions} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Source: [Difference between {} and () with .map with Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592776/difference-between-and-with-map-with-reactjs)

**Example 1:**
[image: Example 1]

**Example 2:**
[image: Example 2]

I have created the following **demo**:
https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-currying-xdt7w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Nope. I have a array of objects from server. Look at update

Comment: I have updated demo, in order to work the mistake was that after using array function mapping data array, you need to return something so you must use () isntead of {}

Comment: @wtsuport worked?