# Creating a table in react using multiple component calls not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a dynamic table of a sudoku app I am working on but I am unable to see why this code *wouldnt* work.
my base app passes in a ref hook and sends the 9x9 array to the Grid component

```
return(
      <Grid arr={sudokuBoard.current.board} />
    )
```

Then in my grid app, it makes a call to the RowComponent using the array.map function

```
export default function Grid(props){
    let sudokuArray = props.arr;
    return(
        <table>
            {sudokuArray.map((row, ind)=> {
                <RowComponent setkey={ind} rowval={row} />
                })
            }
        </table>
    )
}
```

Which then calls a tablecell generation function

```
export default function RowComponent(props){
    return(
        <tr key={props.setkey}>
        {props.rowval.map((item,ind) => {
            <TableItem keyval={item} value={item}/>
        })}
        </tr>
    )
}
```

And the table cell generating component looks like this

```
export default function TableItem(props){
    let tableValue = props.value
    console.log(tableValue)
    return(
        <td>{props.value}</td>
    )
}
```

Any pointers on what could be going wrong? The array gets passed into Grid just fine, but its in the chained calls where things stop working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react/JSX you have to use ( ) around your code block inside the map, instead of { }.  Like this:

```
{sudokuArray.map((row, ind)=> (
  <RowComponent setkey={ind} rowval={row} />
))}
```

```
{props.rowval.map((item,ind) => (
  <TableItem keyval={item} value={item}/>
))}
```

[Difference between {} and () with .map with Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592776/difference-between-and-with-map-with-reactjs) this is an answer that explains why.

Comment: How did I not know this in all my time learning react recently... thanks so much. Will mark this as an answer when its off cooldown.

Comment: @imbes np! I just edited my answer with a post explaining it.